# Maximum value from chained modulo operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, modulo

> If `n = p % q % r` where `p`, `q` and `r` are positive integers and `p` > `q` > `r`, what is the maximum possible value that can be assigned to `n`? (answer in terms of `p`, `q` and/or `r`)

Am I correct that since the expression is evaluated left-to-right, then `n` is equivalent to just `(p % q) % r` and thus regardless of whatever `(p % q)` is, `n` can at most only be `r-1`?

Comment: Your guess is correct.

Comment: Right but if your answer can include a "min" function you can give a more specific answer.

Comment: @MichaelButscher and you can give a more specific comment as to how a "min" function can be included?

Comment: @lefatohy Sorry, I oversaw the inequality condition, my comment is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the maximum value for `n` will be `min(q - 1, r - 1)`.

Because:

```
n = (p % q) % r
```

Then:

If `(q - 1) < (r - 1)`, then `(p % q) < (r - 1)` so `(p % q) % r == (p % q)` and thus `n <= min(q - 1, r - 1)` which is `q - 1`.

If `(q - 1) >= (r - 1)` then (as op described in his question) `n < r - 1` which is `min(q - 1, r - 1)` in that case.

So:

when `p > q > r`, then `min(q - 1, r - 1)` is `r - 1`, so `n` is at most `r - 1`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `n <= r-1`, instead of `n < r-1`?

Comment: Also it is not possible for `(q - 1) < (r - 1)` because `q` > `r` as stated in the question